# Telerik Row Double click only for Gridtable View

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a telerik Radgrid,which has ParentChild Relation Grid.

I want a pop up to open only on the double click of the child grid.Can some suggest on how to implement this.

I used the below JS on the Client Settings RowDblClick Event.It's not working.Please suggest.

```
                function RowDblClick(sender, eventArgs) {



        window.radopen("Details.aspx?ID=" + eventArgs.getDataKeyValue("ID"), "UserListDialog");

    }



                 <MasterTableView  DataKeyNames="ProjectID" AllowMultiColumnSorting="True">
                                        <DetailTables>
                                            <telerik:GridTableView               DataKeyNames="ID"  Width="98%" runat="server">
                                                <ParentTableRelation>
                                                    <telerik:GridRelationFields  DetailKeyField="ProjectID" MasterKeyField="ProjectID">
                                                    </telerik:GridRelationFields>
                                                </ParentTableRelation>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet. You can achieve this thing by using Name property of MasterTableView and GridTableView. Let me know if any concern.

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function RowDblClick(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_tableView().get_name() == "Child") {
                alert('a');
            }
        }
</script>
```

ASPX

```
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ID" CommandItemDisplay="Top" Name="Parent" ClientDataKeyNames="ID">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" HeaderText="ID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>
            <DetailTables>
                <telerik:GridTableView Name="Child" ClientDataKeyNames="ID">
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" HeaderText="ID"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
                </telerik:GridTableView>
            </DetailTables>
        </MasterTableView>
```